# Select with 'negative' offset

Tags: mysql, date, select

I need to select 40 rows with date from today and 10 records with older date, ordered by date.

If MySQL supported negative offset, it would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `date` >= '2013-10-29' ORDER BY date LIMIT -10, 40;
```

Negative offset is not supported. How can I solve the problem? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html) to combine two queries:

```
(
  SELECT   *
  FROM     mytable
  WHERE    date < '2013-10-29'
  ORDER BY date DESC
  LIMIT    10
) UNION ALL (
  SELECT   *
  FROM     mytable
  WHERE    date >= '2013-10-29'
  ORDER BY date
  LIMIT    40
)
ORDER BY date -- if results need to be sorted
```

Comment: Rows are sorted in subqueries so I don't think there is need to sort it again.

Comment: @ElonThan: Firstly, `UNION` does not guarantee that the order of the resultset will be preserved.  Secondly, even if it did, the results from the left-side of the `UNION` will be in descending date order; and the results from the right-side of the `UNION` will be in ascending date order.